# Unable to click on button using the Selenium library in Python because element is hidden (Only able to do so using JavaScript)

Tags: python, selenium

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" href="/user-location-auth/location?id=4013" 
title="View User Location Access" data-toggle="tooltip" data-method="post"> 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></a>    <span 
class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>        <<pseudo:before>> 
</<pseudo:before>>
```

Hi all, I have been tasked with a project that requires clicking on a button in a table (with 14 cells). The first 13 cells are all unhidden, but the 14th one (where the buttons are located), are hidden unfortunately. I have tried action chains, I have tried hovering over the element and then clicking on it. I seem to be at a loss here. This piece of code did work, however I want to avoid using javascript as I want to replicate a user experience.

```
z4 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.btn-success > span.glyphicon-map-marker')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', z4)
```

Comment: where is javascriptExecutor involved in this  code ?

Comment: I'm sorry, just added the correct code to execute using javascript.

Comment: what happens when you use this code `z4.click()` instead of `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', z4)`

Comment: I get the following exception: ElementNotVisibleException

Comment: `z4= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.btn-success > span.glyphicon-map-marker')))`

Comment: after this use `z4.click()`

Comment: Unfortunately I get a TimeoutException in this case.

Comment: You have mentioned that it is a hidden element , what do you do manually to let it become unhidden.

Comment: This pops up before clicking: aria-describedby="tooltip973869

Comment: Please elaborate more , did not get your point

Comment: cruisepandey - thank you for your help. I did some more research and banged my head against the wall some more and just had some success. It turns out using ActionChains fixed this issue. I submitted an answer below for the code that worked for me. Thank you for helping me in this pursuit. I had spent at least 10 hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi everyone and cruisepandey, I found a solution that works. First, I waited for the presence of the element to be located. Once that occurred, I grabbed the element and moved to it with ActionChains (I think I was misusing ActionChains earlier). Then I was able to click on the Bootstrap button.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """
//tr[@data-key='2312312321321']/td/a[contains(@class, 'btn-xs btn- 
success')]/span[contains(@class, 'glyphicon')]""")))

y = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, """//tr[@data- 
key='2312312321321']/td/a[contains(@class, 'btn-xs btn- 
success')]/span[contains(@class, 'glyphicon')]""")

#Use action chains to click on the button
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(y).click().perform()
```